# How to redirect in AngularJS without rendering template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to redirect to an external page from my AngularJS file if the user enter a special url, for instance /test. I have gotten this to work in multiple different ways but all the different ways show a "flash" of the design from index.html. I would like it to go direct without rendering any html at all!

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lotorvik/LfETF/) of one of the examples, but it is not the best place to test since I cant redirect from jsiffle.net :-)

```
$routeProvider.when("/test", {
    resolve: {
        controller: "Redirect"
    }
});
```

Also had one example where I just used a controller and a empty template in the routing, but it gave me the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL(routing) then use,

```
$location.path('the_URL');
```

Comment: You mean I should use $location.path('the_URL'); in the controller? I tried $location.path('http://www.google.com'); but that just got me redirected to the default route.

Comment: In the original question I used $window.location = 'http://www.google.com'; and that redirect work, but I get a "flash" of the style before the redirect.

Comment: So do you want to navigate to a page in your application or do you want to navigate to a different site? This would work if you want to navigate to a page in your application. This would be the path defined in the routeprovider (config)

Comment: I want to navigate to different website. That was what I meant when I asked about "external page" in my question. So what I want is when user enter example.com/test I would like the user to get redirected to google.com without rendering any part of my design. (urls are just examples)

Comment: You can use $window.location.href for website naviagtion. Try it!

Comment: Yeah I said I already used that, but it still show a bit design before it redirects ;-)